# How to insert a line at the middle of table

Tags: tables

I have a multi-column table. I share the code below. I want to put a line at the middle of this table. The line should pass after the 4th column (the first `My-Pipe` column). I couldn't do it. Is there a way to do that ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    *{2}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}}}
\cmidrule{1-4} \cmidrule{5-8} % instead of \toprule
\textbf{col1} & \mc{\textbf{MymcNet}} & \mc{\textbf{Bazilat}} 
   & \mc{\textbf{My-Pipe}} &
\textbf{col1} & \mc{\textbf{MymcNet}} & \mc{\textbf{Bazilat}} 
   & \mc{\textbf{My-Pipe}} \\
& & \mc{\textbf{et al}} & & & & \mc{\textbf{et al}}\\
\cmidrule{1-4} \cmidrule{5-8} 
aa &     &   &    & ac &     &   &    \\
ab &     &   &    & dd &     &   &    \\
bb &     &   &    & de &     &   &    \\
cb &     &   &    & df &     &   &    \\
\cmidrule{1-4} \cmidrule{5-8} % instead of \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption{Test set scores.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

At the end, what should I do to obtain any of the figures below ?

[image]

**EDIT**

I have decided to use @Zarko's suggestion. When I copy and paste the shared code it works perfectly. However, my original table have 2 more columns in each side and therefore I tried to update the solution accordingly. However whenever I try, I got the error shared below. Also, I use this table in a beamer frame. As far as I see, It does not fit to the frame when the number of rows are more than 10. Is there a way to fix it? I have 13 rows as I showed in the edited table.

> ./demo.vrb:24: Misplaced \noalign. \cmidrule ->\noalign 
>                        {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ... l.24 cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule
>                                  (l){7-12}

The code modified by me is the following:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{example}
  \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             l
                        *{5}{S}
                             |
                             l
                        *{5}{S}
                            @{}}
    \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
\textbf{col1}   & {\thead{MymcNet}} & {\thead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\thead{My-Pipe}} & {\thead{nextop1}} & {\thead{nextop2}}
                &
\textbf{col1}   & {\thead{MymcNet}} & {\thead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\thead{My-Pipe}} & {\thead{nextop1}} & {\thead{nextop2}}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
aa  &   &   &  & &    & ac    &   &   &   & & \\
ab  &   &   &  & &    & dd    &   &   &   & & \\
bb  &   &   &  & &    & de    &   &   &   & & \\
cb  &   &   &  & &    & df    &   &   &   & & \\
aa  &   &   &  & &    & ac    &   &   &   & & \\
ab  &   &   &  & &    & dd    &   &   &   & & \\
bb  &   &   &  & &    & de    &   &   &   & & \\
cb  &   &   &  & &    & df    &   &   &   & & \\
aa  &   &   &  & &    & ac    &   &   &   & & \\
ab  &   &   &  & &    & dd    &   &   &   & & \\
bb  &   &   &  & &    & de    &   &   &   & & \\
cb  &   &   &  & &    & df    &   &   &   & & \\
cb  &   &   &  & &    & df    &   &   &   & & \\

cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Test set scores.}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

**EDIT-2**
Finally I was able to escape from the error I shared above. Unfortunatelly I could not able to fit the table into the frame anymore (Eventhouth I did @Zarko 's suggestion. The final code is above:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{foo}
  \begin{table}
        \small
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
        \caption{Statistics.}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                     l
                                *{5}{S}
                                     |
                                     l
                                *{5}{S}
                                    @{}}
            \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
        \textbf{col1}   & \mc{\textbf{mymcNet}} & \mc{\textbf{Bazilat}} & \mc{\textbf{My-Pipe}} & \mc{\textbf{|e1|}} & {\thead{|e2|}}
                        &
        \textbf{col1}   & \mc{\textbf{mymcNet}} & \mc{\textbf{Bazilat}} & \mc{\textbf{My-Pipe}} & \mc{\textbf{|e1|}} & {\thead{|e2|}} \\
        %& & \mc{\textbf{et al}} & & & & \mc{\textbf{et al}}\\
        \cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-12} 
        aa & 230796  & 31372  & 29060  & 363  & 36  & 
        ab & 211820  & 11158  & 10468  & 380  & 47 \\ 
        ac & 417750  & 56515  & 57929  & 269  & 55  &
        ad & 384554  & 37349  & 12069  & 404  & 46  \\ 
        bb & 1174261 & 159437 & 174068 & 2776 & 112 &
        cc & 124336  & 16089  & 15724  & 439  & 45 \\
        dd & 204585  & 25148  & 25096  & 121  & 35  & 
        ff & 112530  & 14063  & 14077  & 1140 & 62  \\ 
        gg & 169283  & 14533  & 13228  & 1129 & 52  & 
        rr & 75964   & 11877  & 11548  & 750  & 39  \\
        uu & 22525   & 12103  & 12410  & 599  & 59   &
        yy & 281057  & 35217  & 35430  & 985  & 43  \\
        uu & 20166   & 11418  & 10448  & 716  & 73  & 
        mm & 148401  & 12344  & 13308  & 540  & 48  \\
        vv & 185113  & 17074  & 16324  & 462  & 59  & 
        zz & 63013   & 10332  & 10897  & 1047 & 56  \\
        kk & 359477  & 36101  & 10090  & 228  & 36  & 
        sd & 31212   & 10139  & 10422  & 355  & 43 \\ 
        gn & 38834   & 10226  & 10199  & 1116 & 67  & 
        rr & 162621  & 18290  & 21041  & 1810 & 89  \\ 
        qh & 80378   & 10332  & 10023  & 159  & 44  & 
        mj & 66645   & 9797   & 20377  & 211  & 40 \\
        vv & 277032  & 12193  & 10652  & 278  & 40  & 
        cz & 186467  & 11458  & 10051  & 335  & 65  \\
        fa & 80575   & 12440  & 13028  & 1294 & 61  & 
        lj & 98608   & 12663  & 12012  & 32   & 12  \\

        \cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-12} 
        \end{tabular*}
        \label{table-stat-ud}
        \end{table} 
\end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Do you know how can I make it working ? The current view is as follows:

[image]

Comment: you talk about frame, but your mwe hasn't any :-(. also, what is text width in your document. default as provided by `article` or can be wider?

Comment: @Zarko yes, I did not include anything about beamer to make it small as much as possible. I am sorry if it is a mistake because I though it isn't  an important difference.

Comment: it is very important. beamer has very different format of text area than standard `article`. also fonts size are very different (large). so this information are crucial.

Comment: @Zarko Now I edited `edit-2` one more time. I hope this time it is in the format you hope to see. I did not change anything in the files that comes with beamer by default.

Comment: i provide you new solution. you can accept it, if you liked. if not, i suggest to close your question as unclear. if you another problems, please ask new question.

Comment: @Zarko thank you for your effort. I accepted your suggestion

Comment: If this is really for a presentation have you thought about a different way to visualise your data? I doubt that people would read the entire table (I certainly wouldn't), but they could get the gist with a nice graph. You can refer them to a printed hand-out or some other place for the full data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             l
                        *{3}{S}
                             |
                             l
                        *{3}{S}
                            @{}}
    \cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
\textbf{col1}   & {\thead{MymcNet}} & {\thead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\thead{My-Pipe}}
                &
\textbf{col1}   & {\thead{MymcNet}} & {\thead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\thead{My-Pipe}}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
aa  &   &   &       & ac    &   &   &    \\
ab  &   &   &       & dd    &   &   &    \\
bb  &   &   &       & de    &   &   &    \\
cb  &   &   &       & df    &   &   &    \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Test set scores.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
i must confess that i went to lost in your sub-questions and lack of essential information. so this is my last try to improve my answer. if you need some further help, please ask new question, that more people can see it and eventually help you. i'm very sure that your basic question is already solved :-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, rotating}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
        \begin{table}
\caption{Statistics.}
\scriptsize
% in the case, that some settings below should be global, move them to preamble
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
%
\sisetup{group-digits}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont mymcNet}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                 l
    S[table-format=7]*{2}{S[table-format=6]}S[table-format=4]S[table-format=3]
                                 |
                                 l
    S[table-format=6]*{2}{S[table-format=5]}S[table-format=4]S[table-format=2]
                                 @{}}
        \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
    \rothead{col1}
        & {\rothead{mymcNet}} & {\rothead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\rothead{My-Pipe}} & {\rothead{e1}} & {\rothead{e2}}
        &
    \rothead{col1}
        & {\rothead{mymcNet}} & {\rothead{Bazilat\\ et all}} & {\rothead{My-Pipe}} & {\rothead{e1}} & {\rothead{e2}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
    aa & 230796  & 31372  & 29060  & 363  & 36  &
    ab & 211820  & 11158  & 10468  & 380  & 47 \\
    ac & 417750  & 56515  & 57929  & 269  & 55  &
    ad & 384554  & 37349  & 12069  & 404  & 46  \\
    bb & 1174261 & 159437 & 174068 & 2776 & 112 &
    cc & 124336  & 16089  & 15724  & 439  & 45 \\
    dd & 204585  & 25148  & 25096  & 121  & 35  &
    ff & 112530  & 14063  & 14077  & 1140 & 62  \\
    gg & 169283  & 14533  & 13228  & 1129 & 52  &
    rr & 75964   & 11877  & 11548  & 750  & 39  \\
    uu & 22525   & 12103  & 12410  & 599  & 59   &
    yy & 281057  & 35217  & 35430  & 985  & 43  \\
    uu & 20166   & 11418  & 10448  & 716  & 73  &
    mm & 148401  & 12344  & 13308  & 540  & 48  \\
    vv & 185113  & 17074  & 16324  & 462  & 59  &
    zz & 63013   & 10332  & 10897  & 1047 & 56  \\
    kk & 359477  & 36101  & 10090  & 228  & 36  &
    sd & 31212   & 10139  & 10422  & 355  & 43 \\
    gn & 38834   & 10226  & 10199  & 1116 & 67  &
    rr & 162621  & 18290  & 21041  & 1810 & 89  \\
    qh & 80378   & 10332  & 10023  & 159  & 44  &
    mj & 66645   & 9797   & 20377  & 211  & 40 \\
    vv & 277032  & 12193  & 10652  & 278  & 40  &
    cz & 186467  & 11458  & 10051  & 335  & 65  \\
    fa & 80575   & 12440  & 13028  & 1294 & 61  &
    lj & 98608   & 12663  & 12012  & 32   & 12  \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-6} \cmidrule(l){7-12}
    \end{tabular*}
    \label{table-stat-ud}
        \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply. Your solution works perfectly but I got error when I try to modify it a little bit. I have edited my question could you look at it one more if possible ?

Comment: in changes you make typo error: you lost ` \ ` before last `cmidrule(r){1-6}` (correct is `\cmidrule(r){1-6}`). however, with enlarging of table, it now spill out of text border and consequently `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` doesn't work properly anymore. you should replace it with `@{}`. probably a little help be use smaller font size (not tested yet).

Comment: I applied the suggestions you provide and edited the question with the final version of the code and snapshot. Eventhough I am able to solve the error, I still couldn't fit the table inside the frame. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: rotate column header?  broken headers into two line? use abbreviation for headers and explain its meaning in caption? without knowing context in table, is difficult to say anything. please, extend your code sniped to complete document beginning with `\documenclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: sure, thank you for all the suggestions. Since it would be easier, I would like to ask is there a way to reduce the sizes between columns ? When I look at the snapshot I shared, it seems there are a lot of unneccesary gaps. If I can decrease that gap, it might be enough for my table to fit ?

Comment: I also tried to convert my code in EDIT2 into MVE.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, based on `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx, tabularx, makecell}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand{\mycmidrules}{\cmidrule(r{10pt}){1-4} \cmidrule(l{2pt}){5-8}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format =2.2, table-column-width=1.8cm}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\let\cmidrulewidth\heavyrulewidth
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
   X*{3}{S}!{\color{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\vrule width 8pt}X*{3}{S}}
\mycmidrules% instead of \toprule
\thead[l]{col1} & {\thead{MymcNet}} & {\thead{Bazilat\\ et al}} & {\thead{My-Pipe}} &
\thead[l]{col1} &{\thead{MymcNet}} &{\thead{Bazilat\\et al}} &{\thead{My-Pipe}} \\
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}
\mycmidrules\arrayrulecolor{black}
aa & & & & ac & & & \\
ab & & & & dd & & & \\
bb & & & & de & & & \\
cb & & & & df & & & \\
\mycmidrules% instead of \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption{Test set scores.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have more than one table and I prefer to keep them consistent. Therefore I want to put a line among them eventhough I still couldn't make it. If possible could you look at my second edit if you have any idea about the solution ?